# Which of the original 151 Pokemon learn moves AS they are evolving?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

> In Pokemon Red and Blue, which Pokemon learn moves at the same level at which they evolve?

or

> Which Pokemon (limited to the original 151) learn moves as they simultaneously evolve?

---

Originally this question was asked somewhere else: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27854 however, the original asker deleted it with in 11 seconds of me trying to post the answer.  Since I spent the time to work out the answer, I wanted to preserve the question.

Comment: If the old question gets un-deleted then I'll have to ask some nice mod to migrate the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the question was about Pokémon Red, Blue, and Yellow specifically. Almost every Pokémon had their movepools and the levels they learnt moves changed from Gen I to the Advanced Generation (Gen III), so here is a list of the Pokémon that learnt moves as they levelled up within the Gen I games (solely Red, Blue, and Yellow):

- **Charmeleon** to **Charizard**, Level 36, Wing Attack
- **Caterpie** to **Metapod**, Level 7, Harden (only Yellow, not Red or Blue)
- **Metapod** to **Butterfree**, Level 10, Confusion (only Yellow, not Red or Blue)
- **Weedle** to **Kakuna**, Level 7, Harden (only Yellow, not Red or Blue)
- **Mankey** to **Primape**, Level 28, Rage (only Yellow, not Red or Blue)
- **Poliwag** to **Poliwhirl**, Level 25, Doubleslap
- **Bellsprout** to **Weepinbell**, Level 21, Stun Spore
- **Slowpoke** to **Slowbro**, Level 37, Withdraw
- **Magikarp** to **Gyarados**, Level 20, Bite
- **Dratini** to **Dragonair**, Level 30, Slam

<sub>(Information compiled from [Serebii.net's RBYGSC Pokédex](http://serebii.net/pokedex/004.shtml)).</sub>

Comment: Actually that was Raven's edit of the original question (which only asked about the first 151).

Comment: Ahh. Well, I was going to answer the original question using the RBY Pokédex anyways, so here is my retro-based answer.

Comment: @Tzenes - I don't see the difference. The question was tagged with the First Generation games -- Red and Blue (and Yellow). There were only 151 Pokémon in those games.

Comment: @Raven Actually the question was tagged [Pokemon] and [leveling], you're the one who changed it to [pokemon-first-gen]

Comment: @tzenes - right. Because the asker specified first-gen.

Comment: @Raven actually the asker looks harassed and angry.  When Keven asks him "Do you mean the Kanto Pokémon within Gen I games, or in a different generation? (The movepools changed from generation to generation.)"  He literally gives up and deletes the question.

Comment: Caterpie learns Harden at Level 7 on evolving to Metapod, and Metapot learns Confusion at level 10 when evolving, in Red and Blue as well. Same with Weedle to Kakuna (for Harden). I used to always catch these PokéMon as bugs first, then level them up in the Viridian Forest.

Comment: @KevinYap Charizard doesn't learn Wing Attack in RBY. Maybe you confused it with GSC?

Answer (score 9):

Now, I might be wrong, but my understanding is that no Pokemon learns moves during the act of evolution.  All moves are learned through: breeding, leveling, or HM/TM.

That said, there are Pokemon who evolve at levels where they also learn moves.  The two mechanisms are disjoint, but can occur at the same time.

For example: Charmander, learns Dragon Rage at level 16.  It also evolves to Charmeleon at level 16.  Thus it can learn Dragon Rage and then evolve after a single battle.

Assuming you want a list of these occurrences the answer is:

Before Evolving

- Charmander to Charmeleon (level 16, learns Dragon Rage)
- Squirtal to Wartortle (level 16, learns Bite)
- Wartortle to Blastoise (level 36, learns Skull Bash)
- Poliwag to Poliwirl (level 25, learns Bubble Beam)
- Geodude to Graveler (level 25, learns Smack Down)
- Magnemite to Magneton (level 30, learns Lock-On)

After Evolving

- Bublbasaur to Venusaur (level 32, learns Petal Dance)
- Charmeleon to Charrizard (leavel 36, learns Wing Attack)
- Metapod to Butterfree (level 10, learns Confusion)
- Kakuna to Beedrill (level 10, learns Furry Attack)
- Rattata to Raticate (level 20, learns Scary Face)
- Ekens to Arbok (level 22, learns Crunch)
- Sandshrew to Sandslash (level 22, learns Crushclaw)
- Oddish to Gloom (level 21, learns Mega Drain)
- Venonat to Venomoth (level 31, learns Gust)
- Digglet to Dugtrio (level 26, learns Mud Bomb)
- Mankey to Primape (level 28, learns Rage)
- Abra to Kadabra (level 16, learns Confusion)
- Ponyta to Rapidash (level 40, learns Fury Attack)
- Slowpoke to Slowbrow (level 37, learns Withdraw)
- Seel to Dewgong (level 34, learns Sheer Cold)
- Gastly to Haunter (level 25, learns Shadow Punch)
- Rhyhorn to Rhydon (level 42, learns Hammer Arm)
- Magikarp to Gyarados (level 20, learns Bite)
- Omanyte to Omstar (level 40, learns Spike Cannon)
- Kabuto to Kabutops (level 40, learns Slash)
- Dragonair to Dragonite (level 55, learns Wing Attack)

Comment: Actually, some Pokemon learn a move after evolving, if the evolution learns it at that level. The classic example is **Kadabra** - it learns Confusion at level 16, *after* evolving from Abra (who does not learn Confusion at all). I haven't the patience to browse all the Pokedexes looking for more though ;)

Comment: @Disgruntled Updated