# Does it matter at which level a Pokémon is given a Moon Stone?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I have a level 16 Nidorino and a Moon Stone. Should I use it right away, or should I wait until Nidorino gets to a certain level? Would it make any difference?

Comment: +1, Good question. This could relate to any generation or stone as well.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29432/what-advantage-do-i-get-by-evolving-my-pokemon

Comment: Also related (actually even possible duplicate): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157930/when-to-use-evolutionary-stones?lq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no easy answer to this. Evolving to Nidoking will increase its stats by a fair amount, but it will not be able to learn as many moves from level up. Compare these two lists:

[Nidorino](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nidorino_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29/Generation_I_learnset#By_leveling_up)

vs.

[Nidoking](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nidoking_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29/Generation_I_learnset#By_leveling_up)

If you're not interested in the moves Nidorino would learn via level up, there's no reason not to evolve it immediately.